# How to have Emacs keybindings everywhere in Macbook Air M1 Monterey 12.5? Is tweaking ~/Library/KeyBindings/ the best approach?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, emacs, library, karabiner

I am new to macOS and a big fan of Emacs. I am trying to achieve *Emacs keybindings everywhere*.

Despite the fact that I have read multiple times on the web [people](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378477/why-emacs-commands-work-everywhere-on-macos) stating that macOS was friendly and out of the box with Emacs keybindings, I am having some hassles. Obviously, the problems happen outside of Emacs. **In Emacs, things work as expected.**

I am struggling with copy, paste, cut, for instance. But I also used to have problems with those in Linux (Ubuntu/NixOs).

Unlike in macOS, in Linux I managed to get `M-b` (move back word) and `M-f` (move forward) to work.

It is possible to do it with `Command-M-b` and `Command-M-f` but I do not want to change my habbit/muscle memory. I want to make this new computer adapt to me - not the opposite.

Some old posts (like [#1](https://lelf.lu/posts/emacs-keybindings-mac-os-x.html), [#2](https://superuser.com/questions/1340224/how-to-enable-emacs-keybindings-on-macos-globally), [#3](https://jhannwong.medium.com/emacs-keybindings-everywhere-35513ce4d09f), [#4](https://blog.sensible.io/2012/10/19/mac-os-x-emacs-style-keybindings-everywhere.html)) mention a tweak on `~/Library/KeyBindings/`. By the way, a lot of posts are mentioning [Jacob Rus' comprehensive guide](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/site/cocoa-text.html) which is hosted on Harvard University domain.... But the link is broken.

Unfortunately, I cannot even find this folder:

```
Pedros-MacBook-Air:Library pedro$ pwd
/Users/pedro/Library
Pedros-MacBook-Air:Library pedro$ cd Key
Keyboard/         Keyboard Layouts/ KeyboardServices/ Keychains/
```

How to find  `~/Library/KeyBindings/` in Mac M1 Monterey 12.5?
Should I create it?

Also, others posting more recent content are suggesting other alternatives, such as [Karabiner-elements](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements) ([#1](https://xenodium.com/improved-ctrl-p-ctrl-n-macos-movement/index.html) [#2](https://irreal.org/blog/?p=9196)). Karabiner-elements can also be useful for [short keys](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x) to launch applications.

What is the best technical practice to change keybindings in macOS?
What are the technical arguments around every solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and trial/error, I have become a heavy user of Karabiner Elements.

This software is really well-crafted. I have been having a great Emacs UX out of Emacs and inside a macOS thanks to Karabiner Elements.

I have even created a GitHub repo to share [my configuration for Karabiner](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-karabiner-elements-config)

I do not have the technical expertise to discuss and contrast the positive/negative aspects of each alternative. What I can state is that [Karabiner-elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) really improved my life.

Answer (score 1):

As for getting your mac adapting to you and your Emacs muscle memory without third-party apps, my option has been, since 2010, to add a `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` inside my `~/Library/KeyBindings/`.

And yes, I did have to make the KeyBindings directory inside ~/Library/ and move my keybindings file into it. (I don't have an M1 Mac, so I can't test it, but I don't see why that would be difficult to achieve. I have an Intel-based 2019 MacBookAir running Monterey 12.6).

I've tweaked (in Emacs, of course) Jacob Rus' DefaultKeyBinding.dict several times since I first copied it in 2010. You can find my version in https://github.com/plgx/DefaultKeybindings.dict/tree/main

You can also adapt it to your needs using for reference Apple's [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html).

(BTW, I'm sure Karabiner Elements is a great piece of software. I'll give it a try soon.)

Comment: Interesting addition. I am glad you are putting it on GitHub. I believe there is a gap on this type of content.