# Why are the Emacs bindings to move around words (such as M-f (option-f) and M-b (option-b)) not working on bash terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, keybindings, emacs

I am using macOS Monterey 12.5 on M1 hardware. In case this can be relevant, I am using an American keyboard with Brazilian Portuguese (ABNT2) as input.

Also, I am using a cool software [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to configure my keybindings. I have made a special effort to create an Emacs UX in macOS. This is [my config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-karabiner-elements-config).

In addition, I am using `bash` and this is my `.bash_profile` file:

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export TFR_RELEASE="xx-xx"
export TFR_DEV="xx-xx"

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

When I am on the terminal, I can use commands such as `C-a` (beginning of line), `C-k` (kill line), `C-f` (character forward), `C-b` (character backward), and others such as `C-u`.

The point that really annoys me is that `M-f` and `M-b` to move around words **do not** work on the terminal. They do work in other parts, such as the bard address of browsers and, obviously, in Emacs.

`M-f` generates this (integral, apparently) "∫" character. And `M-b` generates this (unknowns named for me) "đ" character. Also, `C-M-b` and `C-M-b` do not work either to generate this movement around words. I believe they were the default on macOS to generate this movement.

Considering [this](https://superuser.com/questions/352983/which-emacs-shortcuts-are-useful-in-bash) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378477/why-emacs-commands-work-everywhere-on-macos) question, I thought it would default to have `M-f` and `M-b` keybindings to move forward and backward around words.

How can I solve this?

Comment: There’s a lot going on here. If you make a brand new user account with zero modifications, are you able to sort out if Apple keybindings are in play? I would check zsh in addition to bash if possible.

Comment: `bash` uses readline.  If you want certain keybindings, you need to configure them in ~/.inputrc.

Comment: I do not have such a file. Should I create one?

Comment: If you want to configure keybindings in `bash`, yes.