# Make EMACS control sequences work in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, emacs

One of the reasons I like Apple's software is that I can use emacs control sequences (e.g. ^a to go to the start of the line) in practically any text object.

However, this does not work in Microsoft Outlook, which apparently does not use the Apple Text object.

I'm finding that I want to use Outlook more and more rather than Mail.app, as it doesn't crash and it now has significantly better features.

Is there any way to make ^a, ^e, ^d, ^n, ^f , ^p and the others work in Outlook?

Comment: I don’t know if you can “shoehorn” Emacs control sequences into Word thus the comment vs. an answer, but I wrote about why [Emacs works everywhere in macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378543/119271). Since MS Office apps don’t utilize Cocoa, you don’t get them in those apps.

Comment: I can do it for Microsoft Word main window, and since Word uses the NSText object for many of its fields, emacs works in many of them. I just need to figure out how to do event remapping on a per-app basis...

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-office-for-mac-6bbeb90e-96d9-4e03-b199-fc026ebdc321 -> "To create custom keyboard shortcuts in PowerPoint, Outlook, or OneNote for Mac, you can use the built-in capability in Mac OS X"

Comment: @nohillside - that only works with command-characters, not with control-characters, alas.

Comment: I'm aware of that. You probably could use Keyboard Maestro or similar tools.